Deeplinking is causing wallet connect to return me to home screen instead of my app
i have setup deeplinking in my androidmanifest.xml like this
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="joinclamp.com"
        />
    </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="clampapp" />
    </intent-filter>

now when cliking an https link it opens correctly in my app
but the issue is that my app requires the user to sign in with their wallet app (rainbow wallet or metamask)
const metadata = {
  name: 'Clamp',
  description: 'Clamp mobile app',
  url: 'https://joinclamp.com',
  icons: ['https://joinclam...'],
  redirect: {
    native: 'clampapp://',
  },
};

this is how i have setup the config for the library that mediates between my app and this wallet app
before setting up deeplinking, whenever my app requested user to perform some action in their wallet, they were redirected to the wallet, once the action was complete, they would be redirected to my app
but now the app either takes me to homescreen or takes me to the app from where i had clicked the https link
what to do?

Which library are you using? Did you try removing the 'redirect' and just wait for the signing to complete?

This was an emulator related issue, trying this on different physical devices did not result in the same issue.
